# Facebook friend's wall posting

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

When the user logs in in facebook on my applicaiton, they are able to access their friend's list, select friends and then press on done. A UIView Appears with a list of the names of the friends picked. I would like the app to post a message on the selected friend's wall, or better send a private message, or a request. How can I do it? I really can't understand, and I can't find any specific example codes. I tried this:

```
- (void)postwall
{
NSString *string = @"I reached a score of ";
string = [string stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", highscore]];
string = [string stringByAppendingString:@" can you beat me?"];

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               //kAppId, @"app_id",
                               @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                               @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                               @"Watch Ma Balls", @"name",
                               @"How long can you keep out of the way of ma balls for", @"caption",
                               string, @"description",
                               nil];


[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```

But [facebook dialog, "Facebook" is giving me problems. When I import the file with ought the SDK I get other errors.